# Не могу завершить x-сессию. bash: logout: не командный процессор login: используйте «exit»

Tags: linux

Не могу завершить сеанс пользователя через терминал командой `logout`. Выводится сообщение :

> bash: logout: не командный процессор login: используйте «exit»

Имя текущей среды рабочего стола [`echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`] : lightdm-xsession

Команда `reboot`, `shutdown` - работают.

Конечная строчка ответа команды `cat /etc/lsb-release; arch; lightdm --version` такова: lightdm 1.18.3

---

Мне завершение сеанса нужно было для того,чтобы попробовать избавиться от внезапного зависания системы. Изначально я перезагружал linux, ctrl+alt+F1 и потом в терминале вбивал reboot. Но теперь буду использовать `sudo service lightdm restart`.

Comment: Ну так используйте `exit`.

Comment: думаю, что у exit и logout немного разная семантика.

Comment: Учтите, что `exit` будет работать если команда выполняется напрямую из шелла, а вообще это зависит от DE, которую вы используете. например, для GNOME `gnome-session-quit --force`, для XFCE `xfce4-session-logout`. Для других не знаю, гуглите :)

Comment: не понятно, чего же именно вы хотите добиться. особенно странным выглядит упоминание программ reboot и shutdown.

Comment: тогда вы ищите совершенно не в том месте: внутренняя команда logout интерпретатора bash не имеет никакого отношения к x-сессии, которую вы хотите завершить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутренняя команда logout интерпретатора bash **не имеет никакого** отношения к x-сессии, которую вы хотите завершить.

Справка по внутренней команде *logout* интерпретатора *bash*:

```
$ help logout
logout: logout [n]
    Exit a login shell.

    Exits a login shell with exit status N.  Returns an error if not executed
    in a login shell.
```

Эта команда завершает только сессию, выполненную с логином, т.е., когда интерпретатор *bash* вызван с опцией `-l`.

---

Демонстрация:

```
$ bash
$ logout
bash: logout: not login shell: use `exit'
$ exit
$ bash -l
$ logout
$
```

Comment: всё верно: вы запустили **ещё один** процесс интерпретатора bash (с опцией -l), а потом **его** завершили. // а что значит «перезапустился терминал»?